# Google Sheets API in Angular

Tags: angular, google-sheets-api

I am trying to find how to use the Google Sheets API in Angular. There is no reference to Angular on the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/sheets). I have tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) and it doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone direct me on how I can use the Google Sheets API inside of my Angular application?

I am currently using Angular 8

Comment: Did you check this? https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/google-apis-with-angular-214fadb8fbc5

Comment: "doesnt work" is hardly explaining what exact problem you are having. are you getting any errors?

Comment: check this [repo](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 11):

I made an Angular library exactly for this use case!

With [ng-google-sheets-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-google-sheets-db) you can load data from Google Sheets in a breeze and use [Google Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sheets) as your (*read-only*) backend for your Angular app! You may check out the [Stackblitz example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-google-sheets-db-demo).

### Installation

```sh
ng add ng-google-sheets-db
```

or

```sh
npm install ng-google-sheets-db
```

### Usage

#### Google Sheets

1. Create a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets):

   - The first row **must** be the header.
   - The following rows are your entries, one entry per row.
   - You may have an *active* column, with which you can enable or disable rows/entries.
   - A Google Sheets demo spreadsheet is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gSc_7WCmt-HuSLX01-Ev58VsiFuhbpYVo8krbPCvvqA).
2. Share your sheet:

   - [File] → [Share] → On the bottom of the modal at "Get Link" click [Change to anyone with the link] to be "Viewer".
   - Get the *Spreadsheet ID* (i.e. `1gSc_7WCmt-HuSLX01-Ev58VsiFuhbpYVo8krbPCvvqA`): It is part of the Google spreadsheet URL.
   - Get the *Sheet Name*: The name of the worksheet can be found at the bottom of your Google spreadsheet.
3. Optional: It may be a good idea to enable [2-Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) for your Google account, if you have not done it yet :wink:.

#### Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

A good overview guide is the [Get started as a Workspace developer](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/getstarted-overview).

1. Create a new project in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
2. Enable Google Sheets API: [APIs & Services] → [Enable APIs and Services] → Search for "Google Sheets API" → [ENABLE].
3. Create an *API key*: [APIs & Services] → [Credentials] → [+ CREATE CREDENTIALS] → [API key] → [RESTRICT KEY] → In "Application restrictions" choose "HTTP referrers (web sites)" with "Website restrictions" and in "API restrictions" choose "Restrict key" and select "Google Sheets API" → [SAVE].
4. Get the generated API key.

#### Angular

Add `GoogleSheetsDbService` to your app's module as a provider and Angular's `HttpClientModule` to the imports:

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { API_KEY, GoogleSheetsDbService } from 'ng-google-sheets-db';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: API_KEY,
      useValue: <YOUR_GOOGLE_SHEETS_API_KEY>,
    },
    GoogleSheetsDbService
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Import and inject into your component's constructor:

```js
import { GoogleSheetsDbService } from 'ng-google-sheets-db';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  characters$: Observable<Character[]>;

  constructor(private googleSheetsDbService: GoogleSheetsDbService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.characters$ = this.googleSheetsDbService.get<Character>('1gSc_7WCmt-HuSLX01-Ev58VsiFuhbpYVo8krbPCvvqA', "Characters", characterAttributesMapping);
  }
```

#### Attributes Mapping

The `attributesMapping` maps the Google spreadsheet columns to to your outcome object.

```js
const attributesMapping = {
  id: "ID",
  name: "Name",
  email: "Email Address",
  contact: {
    _prefix: "Contact ",
    street: "Street",
    streetNumber: "Street Number",
    zip: "ZIP",
    city: "City",
  },
  skills: {
    _prefix: "Skill ",
    _listField: true,
  },
};
```

For example, the Google spreadsheet column *Email Address* is mapped to the outcome object attribute `email`.

##### Nested objects

`contact` is an example of a nested object. You may define a `_prefix` as a prefix for all columns of the nested object. Please note that the `_prefix` may need a trailing whitespace.

##### Lists

`skills` is an example of a list. You need to set `_listField` and a `_prefix` for all columns of the list. In this example, all columns starting with _Skill _ and an increasing number are part of the list, i.e. *Skill 1*, *Skill 2*, etc. Please note that the `_prefix` may need a trailing whitespace.

It comes with a [step by step usage guide](https://github.com/FranzDiebold/ng-google-sheets-db-library#usage) and a [demo application](https://franzdiebold.github.io/ng-google-sheets-db-library/)!

Comment: Why it doesnt work now? I am having CORS error... (android real device and website)

Comment: @M.Mariscal Did you publish the spreadsheet? There was a similar issue, see https://github.com/FranzDiebold/ng-google-sheets-db-library/issues/3 for more information.

Comment: @juniortan that's correct. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @FranzDiebold that library looks good, why didn't you include service account auth and write

Comment: @juniortan I only needed a "read-only" database functionality. Write functionality using a "public" API key in a frontend-end app is not a good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Check this article: http://leifwells.com/2016/06/09/ionic-2--angular-2-using-a-google-spreadsheet-as-a-data-source/

You don't need any external package, but to perform a http request to your sheet.

Considering the above you can try something like this:

1. Publish to the web you sheet:

   > Go to your google sheet, then select `File > Publish to the Web`
   >   option which will end up giving you a URL which has an id inside of it
   >   which is important. In our case the url looks like this:
   >
   > `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Kndr-OcyCUAkBUcq6X3BMqKa_y2fMAXfPFLiSACiys/pubhtml`
   >
   > The id that is in this url is:
   >
   > `15Kndr-OcyCUAkBUcq6X3BMqKa_y2fMAXfPFLiSACiys`
2. Create a Google sheet provider (using as reference the first link):

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleDriveProvider {
  data: any = null;

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  public getSheetData(): Observable<any> {
    const sheetId = '15Kndr-OcyCUAkBUcq6X3BMqKa_y2fMAXfPFLiSACiys';
    const url = `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/${sheetId}/od6/public/values?alt=json`;

    return this.http.get(url)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          const data = res.feed.entry;

          const returnArray: Array<any> = [];
          if (data && data.length > 0) {
            data.forEach(entry => {
              const obj = {};
              for (const x in entry) {
                if (x.includes('gsx$') && entry[x].$t) {
                  obj[x.split('$')[1]] = entry[x]['$t'];
                }
              }
              returnArray.push(obj);
            });
          }
          return returnArray;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

*Note:* The example is using Angular 8.

Comment: And what about using spreadsheets that are not shared publicly?

Comment: Have you tried ng-gapi? https://github.com/rubenCodeforges/ng-gapi

Comment: Please update answer to use an example, and I will accept as answer and bounty

Comment: @Gustavo, This is a good interpretation. thank you. Do you know if the observable is supposed to pick on changes to the published spreadsheet? I seem to get a response only once, when the get is being called, but after that, changes in the spreadsheet are not being emitted to the stream.

Comment: @GustavoSantamaría im trying this but it keeps login: ERROR TypeError: res.feed is undefined" in the service (provider)... do you have any hint, please?