# How to read a users google spreadsheet with angular

Tags: angular, google-sheets

I would like users of my app to make a Google spreadsheet and store data in it, that my app can do some calculations on and present in the angular web app's frontend.

Kind of like a dashboard in angular with data coming from their spreadsheet.

The sheet is **not** a master sheet that I maintain, each user maintains their own data.

I don't want to maintain a backend server so I'm hosting essentially a static website (based on angular) on GitHub pages.

Is that possible? How would you go about this?

Comment: This might guide you in a right direction https://youtu.be/K6Vcfm7TA5U

Comment: Actually it was exactly that video that sparked my interest. But, it's done in node and this needs to be a frontend 'thing' where each user has their own sheet and needs their web app browser instance to connect to that.

Comment: Its also possible for the frontend https://stackoverflow.com/a/63550151/9590251

Comment: But there is huge security concern if you do so... Although if its read-only API access, it might be not

Comment: I saw that too. But the thing with that approach is that it is not the users sheet that you consume but one the developer shares. The app could ask for a link to a sheet and then store that link in localstorage but anyone with the link could see the sheet, which is insecure by nature. So, no go. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO and to a smaller extent yes.

Doing such tasks as you have outlined on the front-end cannot be coined as a best practice, but i understand that sometimes, there is just no other way around a problem due to various factors like time.

WHY NO - As per the SHEETS API found @ https://developers.google.com/sheets/api, GOOGLE requires (at least) python2.4 if you are going to consume their API with JS as your prefered language, which will be extraneous to your requirements.

WHY "MAYBE" YES - There are 3rd party API serving sites that could render the service you need (callable REST APIs) that you can call via HttpClient's get method or such such as Datafire's Sheets API. https://app.datafire.io/

PS: The latter option will obviously be MORE expensive.